# Set view a few dips below the center in relativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, centering

I want to have a view which is placed 3 dip below the vertical center line in a relative layout. I can only place it in the excact center. How do you place it 3 dip below?

Comment: did you try setting some margin values?

Comment: @Waqas Yes, but alas, that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a vertical linear layout with two items both of the same weight. The lowest one have a top margin of 3dp. And there you go :)